# Android list item animate text on click

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have a listview and on clicking an item in the list, I want to slide out item's text and open another activity. I have achieved the animation part successfully.

However there is an issue:

When I slide the text out of the screen with setFillAfter(true) and start new activity, how to get the item's text back once the user comes back to listview? I just want text visible on return (without any animation). Currently it is not visible.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng)
{
    //show animation
    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    text= (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.text);

    text.startAnimation(a);
    a.setFillAfter(true);

    // Start Activity
    startActivity(new Intent(MyClass.this, DetailClass.class);
}
});
```

Above is the simplified code. After getting back to list activity, the text remains invisible.

Thanks,

Comment: You should (IMHO) provide a code sample which shows what you are trying to do. I would think that you need to refresh your list in onResume() method of your activity. Please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle.

Comment: @wojci. In onResume() how to refresh just the conccerned list item, not the whole listview?

Comment: What about using the same code in onResume() except use R.anim.slide_out_right instead and obviously exclude the startActivity(). Try working with that.

Comment: How to access View object in OnResume()?

Comment: Do you really have to? You do have a reference to your ListView that you can access in onResume() right? So why not making the list redraw itself using  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#invalidateViews%28%29.

Comment: @VishwaPatel, your soln works but animation in OnResume() may not be a good idea and its jerky too.

Comment: @wojci, invalidateViews() in OnResume() did not make text appear back.

Comment: Why won't it be a good idea? Also, is the jerkiness simply due to the fact that you are running on an emulator or is it due to the fact that the code is in onResume()? I can't think of any technical reason why the animation would be any more jerkier than it would be in onStart().

Comment: I dont know why its jerky, but to solve that I have made animation to move a very small amount. Now seems better. The reason I said anim in onResume() may not be good is it will slow resuming of list activity. My initial anim is in onitemclick, not onStart(). Do you know of how to bring back text without any animation in onResume()? Im testing on Galaxy Nexus. Thanks.